# How to containerize a simple machine learning python application using docker?

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning, flask, containers

The code in this [repo](https://github.com/amirziai/sklearnflask) shows how to create a flask web endpoint to predict probability of 'surviving the titanic disaster'. The trained model is serialized as pickle file using joblib which takes as input age, ticket_class, boarding_location and gender to make the prediction.

Training data - https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

**Architecture of AWS Sagemaker**
[image: Architecture of AWS Sagemaker]
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-hosting.html

The architecture in the above diagram looks like a good way to containerize and deploy ML application.

**Question**

1. How do I use containerize for the ML + flask application in [repo](https://github.com/amirziai/sklearnflask) on my laptop? My objective is to deploy the container in production environment.
2. How do I run the above container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplicity, let's create our image based on Ubuntu.

Create a file `Dockerfile` in an empty directory with the following contents:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Install pip and git and clone repo into /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes --fix-missing python-pip git && git clone https://github.com/amirziai/sklearnflask.git /app

# Change WORKDIR
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Expose port and run the application when the container is started
EXPOSE 9999
ENTRYPOINT python main.py 9999
```

The image can then be built by running `docker build -t <TAG> .` from the directory containing the `Dockerfile`. You can then run it using `docker run <TAG>`.

I imagine you want to add your own sklearn models. There are different ways to do this, e.g. you could change your Dockerfile and use [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) to add files from your local file system to your image, or you could [mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) your model at the point of running the container.

Also, when actually using this container in production, you should consider a few more things, e.g. how to keep your container lightweight (e.g. by using [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/) instead of ubuntu). You'll probably also want to upload your image to a hub, so you can deploy the container from there.

Hopefully this helps as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks! In my ./ I have multiple folders and code. How do I copy them to /app while maintaining the folder structure? Does VOLUME and MOUNT command do the same thing in Dockerfile?

Comment: What is the difference between EXPOSE 9999 and EXPOSE 9999:9999 ?